# React Native Android build cannot download lifecycle-common-java8

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to development build (`yarn android`), but the Android build of React Native got stuck behind this issue, I don't know which package needs this, I made a fresh React Native project and everything was correct there, but on my project, it got stuck. For sure a package needs this, but I haven't got any clue.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform lifecycle-common-java8-2.4.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not find lifecycle-common-java8-2.4.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.4.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-common-java8/2.4.0/lifecycle-common-java8-2.4.0.jar
```

I'm able to download this file by using a browser, but the build procedure cannot download it. even I thought if I know the download place I will put the file there and maybe it helps, but I don't know where does the build procedure use to store the file and then use it.

Comment: I found it out, it happens because I'm located in Iran, the country that got banned by US sanctions, so even by using a VPN, I'm not able to take an Android build of my current project. if anybody knows how to fix this please give me shout here.

Comment: this is a common problem among us my brother.I fix my case once using 'Shekan DNS'.

Comment: @RaminKhodaie, Bro, I already test Shekan DNSz, but have no success so far.

Comment: @AmerllicA Broo also clear DNS cache before running this command

Comment: @AmerllicA once I was struggling with somehow same problem for a week, then I left it and when came back at Saturday without any changes it works and download all packages.it is strange a little :)

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for me:

**Step 1:** creating a socks proxy with ssh tunnel:

`ssh -f -N -M -S /tmp/sshtunnel -D 1086 root@x.x.x.x`

**Step 2:** passing my system traffic through the socks proxy by Shadowrocket (needs m1 macbook)

[image]